# Basic question on automatic differentiation. Why we compute jacobian-vector product

Tags: derivatives, algorithms

I am struggling a bit with automatic differentiation. Let us focus on the forward mode. There are two components of the method I can't put together: The "seeds" and the vector $v$ that multiplies the jacobian.

Let's say we have a function $f(x): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ which is a composite function like
$$
f = f^L \circ f^{L-1} \circ \dots \circ f^{1}
$$

we want to find the Jacobian matrix $J$ of $f$ with respect to $x$. Then with the chain rule we can write

$$
J = J^L J^{L-1} \dots J^{1} 
$$

now in practice I read that the AD algorithm does not actually computes $J$ but the product $Jv$ where $v$ is a vector. (I don't get why at the moment).

From [this](https://rufflewind.com/2016-12-30/reverse-mode-automatic-differentiation) blog post I understand that one has to provide the "seeds" of the derivatives. So I thought that $v$ are the seeds. Is that correct?

If yes, to me it makes sense to always use seeds that are equal to $1$. Is there a reason why sometimes it makes sense to use seeds not equal to $1$?